# WP: How to delete unused taxonomies and terms from the DB?

Tags: database, wordpress, taxonomy

while working on my basic website and creating a custom plugin to add different taxonomies and custom post types, I ended up with several entries in the database that are not useful anymore.

I'm wondering if there's a nice way of deleting them.

Using plugins to clean up the database doesn't work, because these search for orphaned contents. But these taxonomies do exist along with their terms, and I guess there is no reason to consider them orphaned.

They were created with "register_taxonomy" and afterwards added the terms manually.

Thanks a lot!